# How to use FileObserver in Android to Monitor "/sys/class/"

Tags: android, fileobserver

I am trying to monitor the "/sys/class/udc" folder by using `FileObserver`. My app is a system-priv app, so there should not be a permission issue. I am unable to detect the change event.

```
String path = "/sys/class/udc";
static final int mask = (
    FileObserver.CREATE |
    FileObserver.DELETE |
    FileObserver.DELETE_SELF |
    FileObserver.MODIFY |
    FileObserver.MOVED_FROM |
    FileObserver.MOVED_TO |
    FileObserver.MOVE_SELF
);

public UsbCableDisconncetEvent(String path) {
    super(path, mask);
    Log.d(TAG, "DisconnectEventHandler modified");
}

public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    Log.d(TAG, "recieved moified event " + event);
}
```

Does `FileObserver` support the monitoring of "/sys/class" files?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to find out the answer to my question after going through the Android Framework Code.  Those who want to monitor the kernel event(**uevent)** by using FileObesever can refer to the following code :

```
private static final String STATE_PATH = "/sys/class/android_usb/android0/state";
public final UEventObserver mUEventObserver = new UEventObserver() {
       @Override
        public void onUEvent(UEventObserver.UEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "USB UEVENT: " + event.toString());
        }
    };
mUEventObserver.startObserving(USB_STATE_MATCH);

You will start receiving events and should be able to see the same in the logs.
```